# Speech recognition in a client-server application

Tags: client-server, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, mediadevices

I have to implement speech recognition in a client-server application, software needs to be free and work on every browser (except IE). The idea is to create an icon with a microphone, when user clicks it, the speech recognision system activates and records microphone input and when the user says commands like "open X", "homepage", "sign out" the system will redirect to different subsite, return to homepage or log out the user from application. What is the best way to do this? Do it client-side or server-side? Which software to use? If multiple, how to integrate?

I had an idea to send a request to server (by clicking the icon) and start recording on server-side and send the recognised text to client-side and do certain operations based on the output, but I don't think it's possible, or use MediaDevices on client-side to record audio input and send it to pocket-sphinx.js (still on client-side) and get text from it and do certain operations. I'm basically stuck..

Comment: you mention browser, which suggests javascript,. Lots of apprent useful hits: https://www.google.com/search?q=speech+reconition+javascript

Comment: Instead of Pocketsphinx.js I wrote my own server in python which accept voice command from browsers Desktop and Mobile (Firefox/Chrome), do STT either using Pocketsphinx or Sphinx4, process text and send text reply back to browser.
https://github.com/G10DRAS/RoboCop/blob/master/images/FirefoxDesktop.jpg